# Python - How to save CSV files with different file names?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, export-to-csv

I have 5 `DataFrame` with columns *'day'*, *'number'*, *'id'*, *'recordDay'*, and I put all the 5 dataframes in a `dictionary`. I would like to save 5 dataframes in 5 CSV files with file names based on *'id'* and *'recordDay'*. Here's the example of dataframe1 and dataframe2

```
df1                                       df2
     day     number   id   recordDay         day     number   id    recordDay
2017-03-21     17      1   1990-01-01     2016-03-21    6      2   1991-02-01
2017-03-22     19      1   1990-01-01     2016-03-22    8      2   1991-02-01
2017-03-23     21      1   1990-01-01     2016-03-23   10      2   1991-02-01
```

Is it possible to save 5 CSV files with file names like this, `'id_1_1991_01_01.csv'`, `'id_2_1991_02_01.csv'`, `'id_3_1991_03_01.csv'`,`'id_4_1991_04_01.csv'`, `'id_5_1991_05_01.csv'`
Or `'id_1.csv'`...`'id_5.csv'`would be better?

I used the following code, but it only saved one CSV file.

```
pd.concat(df_dict).to_csv('data.csv', index = False, data_format = '%Y-%m-%d)
```

Comment: Why did you think that would save more than one file?

Comment: why don't you save your dataframes before putting them into dictionary? `.df{number}.to_csv('{file_name}.csv', index = False, data_format = '%Y-%m-%d)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the dictionary - using .iloc[] to get the recordID and id values for the name.

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(3, 4), columns=[["day", "number", "id", "recordDay"]])
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(3, 4), columns=[["day", "number", "id", "recordDay"]])
df3 = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(3, 4), columns=[["day", "number", "id", "recordDay"]])

df_dict={"data_frame1":df1, "data_frame2": df2, "data_frame3": df3}

for name, df in df_dict.items():
    #get the id and recordDay values from each df
    df_id=df['id'].iloc[0]
    df_record_day=df['recordDay'].iloc[0]

    #generate a unique file name based on the id and record
    file_name="id_"+str(df_id)+"_"+str(df_record_day)+".csv"

    #create the CSV
    df.to_csv(file_name, index = False, data_format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Or you can use a list of arrays instead of a dictionary

```
df_list=[df1, df2, df3]

for df in df_list:
    #get the id and recordDay values from each df
    df_id=df['id'].iloc[0]
    df_record_day=df['recordDay'].iloc[0]

    #generate a unique file name based on the id and record
    file_name="id_"+str(df_id)+"_"+str(df_record_day)+".csv"

    #create the CSV
    df.to_csv(file_name, index = False, data_format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I convert the `dictionary` into a `list` and run the above code to save the csv files. It works pretty well. Thank you.

Comment: Just changed the answer to reflect using a dictionary - I didn't read carefully enough to realize your dfs were already in a dictionary

Comment: @nanselms2 I just encountered the `TypeError: string indices must be integers` at line `df_id = df['id'].iloc[0]` when using the coding above.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure how your dictionary is set up, if the dataframes themselves are values, then you'll need to use .items() - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python

Comment: I changed the answer to reflect both list and dictionary - a list might be easier/make more sense.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I used `list` and I successfully saved data in csv file.